# Array Serialization Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, serialization, swift3

I have a realm model class with the following properties.

```
import RealmSwift

class UserTrace : Object
{
    dynamic var route_id : String?
    dynamic var place_name : String?
    dynamic var timestamp : String?
    dynamic var date : String?
    dynamic var latitude : String?
    dynamic var longitude : String?
    dynamic var altitude : String?
    dynamic var desc : String?
}
```

I have a function that retrieves the values from the above realm object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let results = Array(realm.objects(UserTrace.self))
let bodyObject = UserTraceList(data: results).data
print(bodyObject)
```

Here, I am trying to serialize the received array with the help of the UserTraceList class.

```
class UserTraceList : NSObject
{
    var data = Array<UserTrace>()

    init(data: Array<UserTrace>)
    {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

The received array format is:

```
[UserTrace {
    route_id = 1;
    place_name = lalitpur;
    timestamp = 1498625530345;
    date = 28/6/2017;
    latitude = 27.6845352254219;
    longitude = 85.3220506757638;
    altitude = 1250.04504394531;
    desc = The user is at latitude 27.6845352254219, longitude 85.3220506757638 at an altitude of 1250.04504394531 on route no 1.;
    }, 
    UserTrace {
        route_id = 1;
        place_name = lalitpur;
        timestamp = 1498626103551;
        date = 28/6/2017;
        latitude = 27.6845773889971;
        longitude = 85.3220016747808;
        altitude = 1250.41149902344;
        desc = The user is at latitude 27.6845773889971, longitude 85.3220016747808 at an altitude of 1250.41149902344 on route no 1.;
}]
```

I want the above array to be in this format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "route_id": "string",
      "place_name": "string",
      "timestamp": "string",
      "date": "string",
      "latitude": "string",
      "longitude": "string",
      "altitude": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```